# How do I find Legendre's Symbol?

Tags: python, math, cryptography, numbers, modulo

Given a 1024 bit modulo and several long integers, I wanted to find out which of these values is a quadratic residue.

The Legendre Symbol is supposed to return -1,0, or 1 and yet my code returns values several orders of magnitude larger than these.

```
 p = 101524035174539890485408575671085261788758965189060164484385690801466167356667036677932998889725476582421738788500738738503134356158197247473850273565349249573867251280253564698939768700489401960767007716413932851838937641880157263936985954881657889497583485535527613578457628399173971810541670838543309159139

ints = [25081841204695904475894082974192007718642931811040324543182130088804239047149283334700530600468528298920930150221871666297194395061462592781551275161695411167049544771049769000895119729307495913024360169904315078028798025169985966732789207320203861858234048872508633514498384390497048416012928086480326832803, 45471765180330439060504647480621449634904192839383897212809808339619841633826534856109999027962620381874878086991125854247108359699799913776917227058286090426484548349388138935504299609200377899052716663351188664096302672712078508601311725863678223874157861163196340391008634419348573975841578359355931590555, 17364140182001694956465593533200623738590196990236340894554145562517924989208719245429557645254953527658049246737589538280332010533027062477684237933221198639948938784244510469138826808187365678322547992099715229218615475923754896960363138890331502811292427146595752813297603265829581292183917027983351121325, 14388109104985808487337749876058284426747816961971581447380608277949200244660381570568531129775053684256071819837294436069133592772543582735985855506250660938574234958754211349215293281645205354069970790155237033436065434572020652955666855773232074749487007626050323967496732359278657193580493324467258802863, 4379499308310772821004090447650785095356643590411706358119239166662089428685562719233435615196994728767593223519226235062647670077854687031681041462632566890129595506430188602238753450337691441293042716909901692570971955078924699306873191983953501093343423248482960643055943413031768521782634679536276233318, 85256449776780591202928235662805033201684571648990042997557084658000067050672130152734911919581661523957075992761662315262685030115255938352540032297113615687815976039390537716707854569980516690246592112936796917504034711418465442893323439490171095447109457355598873230115172636184525449905022174536414781771, 50576597458517451578431293746926099486388286246142012476814190030935689430726042810458344828563913001012415702876199708216875020997112089693759638454900092580746638631062117961876611545851157613835724635005253792316142379239047654392970415343694657580353333217547079551304961116837545648785312490665576832987, 96868738830341112368094632337476840272563704408573054404213766500407517251810212494515862176356916912627172280446141202661640191237336568731069327906100896178776245311689857997012187599140875912026589672629935267844696976980890380730867520071059572350667913710344648377601017758188404474812654737363275994871, 4881261656846638800623549662943393234361061827128610120046315649707078244180313661063004390750821317096754282796876479695558644108492317407662131441224257537276274962372021273583478509416358764706098471849536036184924640593888902859441388472856822541452041181244337124767666161645827145408781917658423571721, 18237936726367556664171427575475596460727369368246286138804284742124256700367133250078608537129877968287885457417957868580553371999414227484737603688992620953200143688061024092623556471053006464123205133894607923801371986027458274343737860395496260538663183193877539815179246700525865152165600985105257601565]

def Legendre(arr,modulo):
    exponent = ((modulo-1)/2)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
      candidate = int(pow(int(arr[i]),int(exponent),modulo)) 
      print("{} : {}\n".format(candidate,arr[i]))

Legendre(ints,p)
```

Comment: int(x) where x is already an int doesn't do anything and makes the code more confusing. In python, integer division use the `//` operator. The `/` operator produces a floating point result.

Comment: There is a legendre_symbol function in sympy: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.residue_ntheory.legendre_symbol

Comment: `p-1` and `-1` are congruent modulo `p`. The expression `pow(a, (p-1)//2, p)` will return 0, 1, or p-1. If it's p-1, your function should replace that with -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p-1` and `-1` are congruent modulo `p`. The expression `pow(a, (p-1)//2, p)` will return 0, 1, or p-1. If it's p-1, your function should replace that with -1.

Here is a fixed version:

```py
def Legendre(arr, p):
    e = (p - 1) // 2
    results = [pow(a, e, p) for a in arr]
    return [(r-p if r > 1 else r) for r in results]
```

There is a legendre_symbol function in sympy: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.residue_ntheory.legendre_symbol

Comparing our fixed version of `Legendre` with sympy's `legendre_symbol`:

```py
from sympy import legendre_symbol

p = 101524035174539890485408575671085261788758965189060164484385690801466167356667036677932998889725476582421738788500738738503134356158197247473850273565349249573867251280253564698939768700489401960767007716413932851838937641880157263936985954881657889497583485535527613578457628399173971810541670838543309159139

arr = [25081841204695904475894082974192007718642931811040324543182130088804239047149283334700530600468528298920930150221871666297194395061462592781551275161695411167049544771049769000895119729307495913024360169904315078028798025169985966732789207320203861858234048872508633514498384390497048416012928086480326832803, 45471765180330439060504647480621449634904192839383897212809808339619841633826534856109999027962620381874878086991125854247108359699799913776917227058286090426484548349388138935504299609200377899052716663351188664096302672712078508601311725863678223874157861163196340391008634419348573975841578359355931590555, 17364140182001694956465593533200623738590196990236340894554145562517924989208719245429557645254953527658049246737589538280332010533027062477684237933221198639948938784244510469138826808187365678322547992099715229218615475923754896960363138890331502811292427146595752813297603265829581292183917027983351121325, 14388109104985808487337749876058284426747816961971581447380608277949200244660381570568531129775053684256071819837294436069133592772543582735985855506250660938574234958754211349215293281645205354069970790155237033436065434572020652955666855773232074749487007626050323967496732359278657193580493324467258802863, 4379499308310772821004090447650785095356643590411706358119239166662089428685562719233435615196994728767593223519226235062647670077854687031681041462632566890129595506430188602238753450337691441293042716909901692570971955078924699306873191983953501093343423248482960643055943413031768521782634679536276233318, 85256449776780591202928235662805033201684571648990042997557084658000067050672130152734911919581661523957075992761662315262685030115255938352540032297113615687815976039390537716707854569980516690246592112936796917504034711418465442893323439490171095447109457355598873230115172636184525449905022174536414781771, 50576597458517451578431293746926099486388286246142012476814190030935689430726042810458344828563913001012415702876199708216875020997112089693759638454900092580746638631062117961876611545851157613835724635005253792316142379239047654392970415343694657580353333217547079551304961116837545648785312490665576832987, 96868738830341112368094632337476840272563704408573054404213766500407517251810212494515862176356916912627172280446141202661640191237336568731069327906100896178776245311689857997012187599140875912026589672629935267844696976980890380730867520071059572350667913710344648377601017758188404474812654737363275994871, 4881261656846638800623549662943393234361061827128610120046315649707078244180313661063004390750821317096754282796876479695558644108492317407662131441224257537276274962372021273583478509416358764706098471849536036184924640593888902859441388472856822541452041181244337124767666161645827145408781917658423571721, 18237936726367556664171427575475596460727369368246286138804284742124256700367133250078608537129877968287885457417957868580553371999414227484737603688992620953200143688061024092623556471053006464123205133894607923801371986027458274343737860395496260538663183193877539815179246700525865152165600985105257601565]

our_results = Legendre(arr, p)
sympy_results = [legendre_symbol(a, p) for a in arr]

print(our_results)
print(sympy_results)
# [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
# [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```